# what meaning of XYZ in format 00:00:00.XYZ ? millisecond of microsecond?

Tags: oracle, datetime-format

I want to measure SQL execution in Oracle and I got time like
`Elapsed: 00:00:00.XYZ` 
I confused,is it millisecond or microseconds?

Comment: Micro is 6 digits and milli is 3 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `00:00:00.XYZ`, the elapsed time is `XYZ` milliseconds. The dot separates the whole seconds from the second's decimal places.